# Dynamically create imageView in ViewFlipper getting imageView id

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, viewflipper

I have dynamically created imageView in my ViewFlipper and it runs smoothly. However, when I want to click the image I need to do an enlargement of the image and do something with it. How do i get the id. I need to be able to differentiate which image i have clickeded.

Thanks in advance.

```
    public class Home_Fragment extends Fragment{

.....

   private ViewFlipper vf;

    int gallery_grid_Images[]={R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d};

  private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
        //Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res+"");
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());



        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        image.setLayoutParams(lp);

        image.setAdjustViewBounds (true);
        image.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        image.setClickable(true);

        image.setBackgroundResource(res);

        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id=(Integer) v.getTag();     //---> This will crash if i click the image
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), id+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        vf.setTag(res);

        vf.addView(image);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Below code i have used for viewflipper for sliding image.you can add onclick event of image inside forloop.

**SlideShowActivity.java**

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class SlideShowActivity extends Activity {

private ViewFlipper myViewFlipper;
private float initialXPoint;
int[] image = { R.drawable.one_full, R.drawable.two_full,
    R.drawable.three_full, R.drawable.four_full, R.drawable.five_full,
    R.drawable.six_full, R.drawable.seven_full, R.drawable.eight_full,
    R.drawable.nine_full, R.drawable.ten_full };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.slide_show);
myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myflipper);

for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(SlideShowActivity.this);
    imageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
    myViewFlipper.addView(imageView);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       // your code
   }});
} 

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    initialXPoint = event.getX();
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    float finalx = event.getX();
    if (initialXPoint > finalx) {
        if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == image.length)
            break;
        myViewFlipper.showNext();
    } else {
        if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
            break;
        myViewFlipper.showPrevious();
    }
    break;
}
return false;
}
}
```

Here the images are only changing while user is swipe.

If you want to swipe automatically with certain interval add the following code.

```
myViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
myViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
myViewFlipper.startFlipping();
```

Comment: my viewflipper currently is auto and is like 30% screen size. my intention is when it is clicked, the device will require to put the image into a fragment and show it. Therefore i need the imageView id.  My code currently able to detect the click like what you did. It just how to get the image source to put into my fragment that is my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To post my research, I am able to know which image I clicked. image.setId(tagNum);  tagNum running from 0 to max number of imageView i created-1. when clicked, the number is shown correctly in log.  I can use that number to find the image source in my array.

```
private void setFlipperImage(int res, int tagNum) {

    ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    image.setLayoutParams(lp);

    image.setAdjustViewBounds (true);
    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    image.setClickable(true);
    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
    image.setId(tagNum);

    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //vf.getTag(key);

            int id = vf.getCurrentView().getId();

            Log.d("Value id", Integer.valueOf(id).toString());



        }
    });

   // vf.setTag(res);
    vf.addView(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `image.setTag()`. Set an unique tag for each imageView and onClick get that tag and determine which imageView you clicked.

```
int id=(Integer) v.getTag();
```

The above line crashes may be its getting null.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I am new to android programming, as you can see I did use vf.setTag(res);  This lead to another issue when i use getTag(res);   how do I know which res value i am currently selected.

Comment: your onClick(View v) is for imageView click event. So if you take int id=(Integer) v.getTag();  you will always get image view id.

Comment: Yup, don't bother that line of code, I can use v.findViewById if the imageView is created in .xml, but now imageView is created by code. Is there a way to refer the imageView without using xml?  Can I set ID my self?